# Posting picture on a friend's wall?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post a picture in a friend's wall?
I'm using this code :

```
Bundle postdata = new Bundle();
postdata.putString("message", msg);
postdata.putByteArray("picture", pic);
// this code, i found it in another questions but it doesn't
// seem to help much:
postdata.putString("target_id", usr);
// then i  use the Asynchronous request.
mAsyncRunner.request(usr+"/feed", postdata, "POST",new WallRequestListener(), null);
```

where `pic` is the picture as a byteArray and `usr` is the friend's ID.
It just shows the message on the friend's wall but no picture at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my app. And it works.

```
protected void uploadPhoto() {
    if (!Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "You must first log in.");
    } else {
        if (targetUri != null) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            try {
                params.putByteArray("photo", Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), targetUri));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            params.putString("caption", txtPhotoCaption.getText().toString());
            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request( "replace this with the users ID"+ "/photos&access_token=" + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken(), 
                    params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
            txtPhotoCaption.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that I am using the same method as used in the sample app. Without getting into the pros or cons of scaling or not scaling the image. The "**caption**" attribute is being pulled from an EditText. And the actual image is in the field "**targetUri**", which is declared as a global variable. It's fetching the image using the default Gallery on the device. For the sake of completeness, this is the code to grab the image from the default Gallery app. (this prompts the user to select the app)

```
btnAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

And it is processed in the `onActivityResult()` here:

**NOTE**: *I am also setting the selected image in an ImageView as a preview to the logged in user*

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)    {
            targetUri = data.getData();
            Log.e("IMG URI", targetUri.toString());
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
                try {
                    Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), targetUri);
                    imgDisplaySelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have again tested an upload to a friends wall before I posted the code here as an answer. And it really works. Hope this helps you as well.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the latest comment, using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT did not play nice with the preview image display under the onActivityResult(). Modifying the code a little worked.

What I find strange is the fact that in the "Complete action using" popup, I did not get the Astro File Manager nor the Gallery on my Galaxy S. It gives me File Manager (off the market, not the stock) and Quickoffice Pro. That being said, selections from either the two still works and photos still upload.

Comment: Sure thing. Just take the right part from the code above, and it should be good.

Comment: thank you very much mate. I only had to change this line: "usrID/photos&access_token=" i was using "usrID/feed".

Comment: now, you say you use the default gallery to select a picture, when i try to use that it only shows the zoom options for the picture, I can only select a picture using the "Astro file manager", any ideas on what might the problem is? the only difference with your code is that I'm using "Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT" instead of Intent.ACTION_PICK

Comment: im away from my computer at the moment. Will see what I can do first thing in the morning. Is it generating any errors?

Comment: no, that's the weird part, it doesn't throw any errors it just doesn't do anything when i select a picture using the default.. file manager?, it only works using that astro FM.

Comment: Interesting find here. Using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not bring up Astro File Manager or the Gallery options in the selection list. But I did get a crash (updated answer for details). But selection from File Manager works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) the name of the parameter for the picture is not *"picture"* but *"source"*.

So your code should be:

```
Bundle postdata = new Bundle();

postdata.putString("message", msg);
postdata.putByteArray("source", pic);

mAsyncRunner.request(usr + "/feed", postdata, "POST", new WallRequestListener(), null);
```

Comment: Wait, you're trying to post to the user feed, that path does not expect a picture. If you check [the docs.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) you'll see that the "picture" param is a String. What are you trying to do? Post an image to the wall photos?

Comment: yeah actually i use the first code with the "picture" parameter to upload pictures to the user's wall but i do that getting the Wall album ID, but now i want to post a picture in the user's friend wall.

Comment: So here too you will need to get the id of the album in order to post to it.